# Cloning git repository inside CLI with Typescript & Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, github, command-line-interface, clone

I'm writing my `CLI` in `nodejs` with `typescript`.
I need to clone git repository and after that run `npm i`.
I need to authenticate agains github with **credentials or SSO**. How and if it's possible to implement? I have tried `octokit/rest` but without any success.
Seems like this lib is deprecated.

Can you please suggest me which one to or how to implement it?

```
export class GitAuthManager {
    private readonly appHubRepositoryUrl = 'https://github.';
    private readonly umsRepositoryUrl = 'https://github';
    private git: SimpleGit;
    private octokit: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    getInstance() {
        return this.octokit;
    }

    gitAuthToken(token: string) {
        this.octokit = new Octokit.Octokit({ auth: token });
    }

    async getPersonalAccessToken() {
        const credentials: GitAuthAnswer = await askGithubCredentials();
        const status = new Spinner('Authenticating you, please wait...');
        status.start();

        this.octokit = new Octokit.Octokit({ auth: `${credentials.username}:${credentials.password}` });

        const payload = {
            note: `your token`,
            scopes: ['user', 'public_repo', 'repo', 'repo:status', 'delete_repo', 'gist']
        }

        try {
            const { data } = await this.octokit.oauthAuthorizations.createAuthorization(payload);
            console.log(data)

            return data;
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(`Error creating GitHub token\n${ err.message }`);
        } finally {
            status.stop();
        }


        this.git.clone(this.umsRepositoryUrl, [], () => {
            console.log('Completed cloning...');
        });

    }
}`
this is my implementation. Which doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [github deprecated http basic auth at Nov 13, 2020](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/)

You cannot authenticate with credentials(username & password) for sure.
You can take a look at using oauth as described at [github offical oauth documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#web-application-flow)

Then you can use [octokit/auth-oauth-app](https://github.com/octokit/auth-oauth-app.js) to help you authenticate with github, or just append the access token in the header of your request like:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token my-oauth-token' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer can you please point me out to the correct example. Seems like they forgot to update their documentation.